# How does SGD Incremental Learning behave in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am going through the incremental learning algorithm in Scikit-learn. SGD in sci-kit learn is such a kind of algorithm that allows learning incrementally by passing chunks/batches.

- Does sci-kit learn keep all the batches for training data in memory?
- Or does it keeps chunks/batches in memory up to a certain amount of size?
- Or does it keep only one chunk/batch while training in memory and removes the other trained chunks/batches after training? Does that mean it suffers from catastrophic forgetting?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of incremental learning is to *not* keep the whole training data in memory. Thus, it is possible to learn on big data sets that would not fit in memory as a whole. Incremental learning is also useful if the training data becomes available piece by piece.

Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) keeps no batches in memory, except the one it is working on. However, that does not mean it immediately forgets past patches. Batches are used to compute the gradient, which is used to update the model coefficients. So information contained in the batches remains in the model although the data itself is discarded.

Since the gradient is updated with the most recent batch, newer batches have more influence on the current training state of the model than older batches. You could say that recent batches are more vivid in the model's memory while it gradually forgets older batches.

Here is a toy example to illustrate this issue (code at the bottom):

[image]

An SGD classifier was trained incrementally with three classes in the first 100 batches. In batches 100-200 *class 3* was not present in the training data. It is very apparent that the classifier "forgets" everything it had learned about this class before. You may label this effect "catastrophic forgetting", or you may see it as desirable "adapting to changes in data"; the interpretation depends on the use case.

So, yes, SGD indeed seems to suffer from [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference). I do not think it's a big deal, though; just something you have to be aware of when designing the training strategy in a particular application.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)
n_features = 150
centers = np.concatenate([np.eye(3)*3, np.zeros((3, n_features-3))], axis=1)

x_test, y_test = make_blobs([100, 100, 100], centers=centers)

cla = SGDClassifier()
performance = []

def train_some_batches(n_samples_per_class):
    for _ in range(100):
        x_batch, y_batch = make_blobs(n_samples_per_class, centers=centers)
        cla.partial_fit(x_batch, y_batch, classes=[0, 1, 2])
        conf = confusion_matrix(y_test, cla.predict(x_test))
        performance.append(np.diag(conf) / np.sum(conf, axis=1))

train_some_batches([50, 50, 50])
train_some_batches([50, 50, 0])            

plt.plot(performance)
plt.legend(['class 1', 'class 2', 'class 3'])
plt.xlabel('training batches')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering if there is any difference between the 'partial_fit' and the regular 'fit'.

Comment: @Farzana well, the regular `fit` is the ultimate forgetting experience. It completely trains the classifier from scratch with whatever data you provide.

Comment: Sorry to ask you the same thing again. I am just trying to make sure that I understand it clearly. So, what I understand is 'fit' completely forgets what it learns after the classification but 'partial_fit' forgets gradually. Am I right?

Comment: @Farzana almost. `partial_fit` updates the classifier but `fit` "overwrites" it. If you call 'fit' multiple times, only the last one matters.

Comment: > only the last one matters
...unless `warm_start` is True